# Why am I seeing a dropdown like thingy and need to "open" my Angular component in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome

Why am I seeing this instead of the content of my Angular "Details" component in Chrome and not in IE11 ?

[image: Details component]

If I "open" the drop down like thingy I see the content, but why am I getting this instead of the content ?

Comment: Perhaps try inspecting to see if the styles are different between the two browsers?

Comment: Are you talking about inside the web page, or in the developer tools?

Comment: Yes, inside the web page.  So I have a webpage before that which has a routerlink to open the details component... and for some reason this shows up in Chrome as little drop down thingy, but not in IE11.

Comment: The class the dropdown has is ng-star-inserted by the way

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the culprit, seems that '**details**' is a bad selector for an angular component... since HTML5 already contains a `<details>`-tag.
So don't use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
```

rather use:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'detailsWhatever',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
```

Or any other selector that is not just `'details'`.
Doh!